# how do I factor this $6a^2+ 70ab$?

Tags: factoring

how to factor $6a^2+ 70ab$ ?

I got this:

$$6a^2+ 70ab = 2a ( 3a + 35b ) $$

Is the factorization complete ?

Comment: if you're question is clear any level is allowed. feel free but don't take this as HW site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is not much else you could do, assuming $a$ and $b$ have no constant factors.